# Is there a library class to represent floating point numbers?

Tags: c++, floating-point, decimal

I am writing an application which does a lot of manipulation with **decimal** numbers (e.g. 57.65). As multiplications and divisions quickly erode their accuracy, I would like to store the numbers in a class which preserves their accuracy after manipulation, rather than rely on float and double.

I am talking about something like this:

```
class FloatingPointNumber {
private:
    long m_mantissa;
    int m_dps; // decimal points
    // so for example 57.65 would be represented as m_mantissa=5765, m_dps=2
public:
    // Overloaded function for addition
    FloatingPointNumber operator+(FloatingPointNumber n);
    // Other operator overloads follow
}
```

While it is possible for me to write such a class, it feels a bit like reinventing the wheel and I am sure that there must be some library class somewhere which does this (although this does not seem to exist in STL).

Does anybody know of such a library? Many thanks.

Comment: Yes the datatype you're looking for is called decimal. It's not a floating point type however. It's the datatype to use when representing money for example.

Comment: ...? He asked if such a library exists. You said, 'Yes, ...'

Comment: Well then I expressed myself in a fuzzy manner. What I was trying to say was that this type is commonly called "decimal", which would give him pointers what to look for.

Comment: If you want to represent money, just store it in terms of the small units of money, and then convert it later if for example you want to represent it to a human.

Comment: I know that the data type decimal exists in C#, but not in C++ hence the original question.

Comment: Forgive me for trying to help.

Answer (score 5):

Do you mean something like this ?

```
#include "ttmath/ttmath.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   // bigdouble consists of 1024*4 bytes for the mantissa
   // and 256*4 bytes for the exponent.
   // This is because my machine is 32-bit!
    typedef ttmath::Big<1024, 256> bigdouble; // <Mantissa, Exponent>

    bigdouble x = 5.05544;
    bigdouble y = "54145454.15484854120248541841854158417";
    bigdouble z = x * y * 0.01;

    std::cout << z;

    return 0;
}
```

You can specify the number of **machine words** in the *mantissa* and the *exponent* as you like. 
I have used [TTMath](http://www.ttmath.org/ttmath) to solve Project Euler puzzles, and I am really pleased with it. I think it is relatively stable and the author is very kind if you have questions.

---

**EDIT::** I have also used [MAPM](http://www.tc.umn.edu/~ringx004/mapm-main.html) in the past. It represents big floats in **base 100**, so there would be no problem converting decimal numbers to base 100, unlike base 2. TTMAT uses base 2 to represents big floats. It is stable since 2000 as the library page claims. It has been used in many applications as you can see in the library page. It is a C library with a nice C++ wrapper.

```
MAPM nextPrime(){

    static MAPM prime = 3;
    MAPM retPrime = prime;

    prime += 2;
    while( isPrime( prime ) == false )
        prime += 2;

    return retPrime;
}
```

---

BTW, If you are interested in GMP and you are using VS, then you can check the [MPIR](http://www.mpir.org/) which is GMP port for Windows ;) for me I find TTMath more than pleasing and easier/faster than all of what I tried because the library does stack allocations without touching the heap in anyway. Basically it is not an arbitrary precision library, you specify the precision at compile-time as shown above.

Answer (score 3):

There is a list of libraries [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic#Libraries).

I have never tried any of them so I can't recommend a single one, however [this one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Multi-Precision_Library) is part of the GNU Project so it can't be half bad.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to roll your own, [Binary Coded Decimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal) is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

- [A list of decimal arithmetic packages](http://speleotrove.com/decimal/), included Robert Klarer’s decNumber++, which implements the interfaces specified in the forthcoming ISO Technical Report on decimal arithmetic types in C++: ISO/IEC TR 24733: C++ Decimal Floating-Point Arithmetic Extensions
- [The Multiple Precision Floating point with correct Rounding library](http://www.mpfr.org/), but if I remember correctly, it is binary floating point

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with these libraries, but just as a matter of awareness, there have been 2 major developments that I think are relevant to this question in the last few years...

1. "posits" - a new floating-point format that is more efficient and less "messy" than IEEE754.
2. C# 11 has introduced "static abstract interface members" which enables (for our purposes) implementing new numeric types while getting all the same benefits of the built-in numeric types in terms of operator overloading, etc...  i.e. truly generic numeric types in C#.

I know of no implementations of "posits" in C#, nor is C# 11 released yet.  But again -- these are salient developments related to the question.